# GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=McNiz_D 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am creating a server based on websocket in nodejs as a back-end and ionic 4 app as a front-end , when i am trying to connect to my server i get this error

`GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=McNiz_D 404 (Not Found)`

Here is my server code

```
const PORT = 8080;
const WebSocket = require("ws").Server;
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
 res.header(
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
);
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
 next();
});
var http = require("http").createServer(app);

http.listen(PORT, "localhost", function() {
console.log("listening in http://localhost:" + PORT);
});
const wss = new WebSocket({ server: http });
 wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
  console.log("received: %s", message);
 });
 ws.send("I am server ^_^");
});
```

Comment: Can you post your frontend code? seems like you are using websockets protocol in backend and socket.io in frontend

Comment: Thank you , That was the problem but what the error does mean ?

Comment: Please refer the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference and as you want more clarification, this was happened because using websockets protocol in backend and socket.io in frontend instead of plain WebSockets client.

---

When socket.io want to connect to the server the [upgrade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism) request is sent to `http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=McNiz_D 404` this path. Since there is no socket io server is configured in the backend, obviously express server send `404 not found` instead of the upgrade response.

Comment: Hi, We are facing a similar issue when we are using S3 bucket to host our application which is serverless. 

as your answer suggests socket io also need a server at the back end to have a complete hand shake, is there any way we can achieve this?